# Is it necessary use thread-safe methods when i use AsParallel?

Tags: c#, linq

When i use `AsParallel()`, the next operations runs in multi-thread, so, the methods that i use in this query, should be a thread safe?

In the next example, the method `Convert(string value)` is not thread-safe but is being used in a `Select()` that run as `AsParallel()`.

Is it correct to use `AsParallel()` like standar `Linq`?

Note: The `Convert()` method it's just an example, but imagine a more complex method that really required a thread-safe implementation, when it will be executed in a multi-thread environment.

```
List<string> myNamesList = new List<string>()
{
   //Initialize with a lots of elements
}

List<string> myConvertedNameList = myNamesList.AsParallel()
                                               .Where("Any Condition")
                                               .Select(x => Convert(x)) 
                                               .ToList();
```

```
public string Convert(string value)
{
    int length = value.Length;
    string myFantasticValueConverted = "_" + value + "["+ length +"]";
    return myFantasticValueConverted;
}
```

Comment: The `Convert` method you've posted is thread safe.

Comment: use System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T> istead of List<>

Comment: Concurrency and locking are the hardest things to get right
when it comes to multithreaded programming. Getting it wrong can hurt
performance and even cause incorrect calculations. But, It's important when you're using Parallel LINQ to query datasets, that you don't lose sight of the best place for the query to be executed. You may speed up a query in the application with parallelization, but the best place for the query to occur may still
be in the database, which can be even faster. So that might introduce a different way of attacking this performance issue you're trying to tackle.

Comment: @oetzi - that won't help at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use thread-safe methods when I use AsParallel?

Yes.

Comment: @EricJ. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-and-execute-a-simple-plinq-query#example explicitly states that `ToArray` and `ToList` are fine.

Comment: @Brian: That's correct, but let's be clear: `ToArray` and `ToList` are fine *when they are converting the result of a parallel process to an array or a list*. But they are *not* fine *when being used in the parallel process itself on a receiver that is not threadsafe for enumeration on multiple threads*. Context matters.

Comment: I deleted my original comment because I misunderstood where the commenter was suggesting using a `ConcurrentBag<T>`. Turns out, he was suggesting using it for the source. I believe that's also unnecessary as `List<T>` is thread-safe with regard to read (but not altering) operations.

Comment: @EricJ.: That's correct; it is safe to use a list on multiple threads provided that all the threads are reading and none are writing. Note that this is not necessarily true of all collections! Suppose for example we implement a hash set using the standard hashing with chaining.  A reasonable optimization is to detect if there is a long chain that is being frequently read, and if it is, to move the element being read *most* to the head of the list. This mutates the internals of the data structure on read, so this can cause a read-only operation to be not thread safe.

Comment: While Eric Lippert's warning is valid, it is worth noting that all `System.Collections.Generic` collections are safe for concurrent reads.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/ .

Comment: So, should i implement my Convert method adding a `lock(obj){ //code }` block?

Comment: @GonzaloMartinez: **Absolutely not**.  That would completely destroy all the benefits of parallelism!  You would create a dozen threads and then they would all be idle waiting for each of them to finish in turn; how would that improve performance? It would degrade performance!  **You have to write the method so that it is thread safe without taking out any locks!** There is no benefit to parallelism if you're just going to turn it off again with a lock!

Comment: @GonzaloMartinez: Think about it this way. Suppose you have a whole lot of cars driving around on streets, but they are hitting each other because the streets are narrow. What do you do? You have two choices: destroy throughput by putting lights on every corner so that almost all traffic is stopped waiting for something, or build a freeway with enough lanes that the cars can travel in parallel without hitting each other. What you are suggesting doing is building the freeway *and then putting the traffic lights on the freeway too*.  That makes performance worse.

Comment: @GonzaloMartinez: But if all you are doing is running a tiny little method on each member of a collection, do not use parallelism at all. Use parallelism when you have *minutes* or *hours* of work to do for each item, not *microseconds*.  You'll spend more time spinning up threads than it will take them to do the work.

Comment: @EricLippert - there is very little documentation that quantifies this, but "minutes or hours" is way too high. When using Threads directly the break-even point is in the millisecond range, for Tasks it is a lot lower, microseconds. With wide margins everywhere for external factors etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Though I agree that your estimates are in the right ballpark, the question is not just "when do we possibly get any win?" The germane question is "**when do we get enough user-appreciated win that it justifies the added time and expense of writing an asynchronous or parallel workflow?**" If the user sees their program go from taking 10 milliseconds to 7 or 5 or even 1, the user the vast majority of time does not care. But taking a rendering from 10 minutes to 7 or 5 or 1 minute is a win people notice, and so worth the cost.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's why I recommend that people not use parallelism unless they're talking about wins that are measured by a wall clock, and I recommend that people not use tasks unless the synchronous workflow would impose a 30ms penalty or greater. People notice a 30ms UI lag -- barely, but they notice it -- and so it is worth the expense of rearchitecting your workflow to fix that.